# can I run a scala application through node.js?

Tags: node.js, scala, sbt

I have a scala library and I can use it to build a scala application. But I want to use that library in node.js or I want to control that scala application from node.js.

Can that be done somehow ?

Comment: One way would be to expose the Scala library as an API that the nodejs application can query via HTTP requests.

Comment: this seems interesting, can you tell me how that can be done as I have not much experience in scala!

Comment: Scala can be compiled to javascript, so depending on the library it might be possible to run it natively on node.js.

Comment: Consider that not every Scala application and library is supported or compatible with Scala-JS.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at a project called [Scala.js](https://www.scala-js.org/). Assuming you have the source code of the library you wish to use, you should be able to add [`@JSExport` annotations](https://www.scala-js.org/doc/interoperability/export-to-javascript.html) and compile it to JavaScript to use in a JavaScript environment, including Node.js and the browser.

For instance, take a look at this sample Scala class (from the Scala.js documentation):

```scala
class Foo(val x: Int) {
  override def toString(): String = s"Foo($x)"
}
```

To export the class to be usable from JavaScript, just add `@JSExport` before the class and any functions you wish to export:

```scala
@JSExport
class Foo(val x: Int) {
  // Just as a note, @JSExport isn't required on toString.
  @JSExport
  override def toString(): String = s"Foo($x)"
}
```

Now, you should be able to `require` that file from a hand-written file and use it just like a normal JavaScript class!

```
const Foo = require('./compiled-file-name').Foo;
var foo = new Foo(3);
console.log(foo.toString());
```

DISCLAIMER: I have never used Scala.js, this is simply taken from the documentation.

Comment: I tried that and end up with these errors:
`code`
[error] Referring to non-existent class edu.knowitall.openie.OpenIE$
[error]   called from tutorial.webapp.TutorialApp$.<init>()
[error]   exported to JavaScript with JSExport
[error] Referring to non-existent class edu.knowitall.openie.OpenIE
[error]   called from tutorial.webapp.TutorialApp$.<init>()
[error]   exported to JavaScript with JSExport
`code`
Actually I am trying to use Open IE scala standalone version from node.js so I am stuck here!